# Mismatch between Matlab log and Numpy np.log

Tags: numpy, matlab, precision, numeric, logarithm

While rewriting an old Matlab code to NumPy, I noticed differences in logarithmic calculation.
In NumPy, I use `np.log`, Matlab uses `log` function.

```matlab
b = [1 1 2 3 5 1 1];
p = b ./ sum(b);
sprintf('log(%.20f) = %.20f', p(5), log(p(5)))
```

```py
import numpy as np
b = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 1])
p = b.astype('float64') / np.sum(b)
print(f'log({p[4]:.20f}) = {np.log(p[4]):.20f}')
```

For my MacBook Pro 2020 with M1 chip, I get mismatch at 16th decimal digit.

```
log(0.35714285714285715079) = -1.02961941718115834732  # Matlab
log(0.35714285714285715079) = -1.02961941718115812527  # NumPy
```

I would like to get **exactly** the same results. Any idea, how to modify my Python code?

Comment: Does that difference really matter for your specific application? Keep in mind that neither of those numbers are actually correct. As per WolframAlpha, ln(5/14) = -1.029619417181158 **239921825531675168658**...

Comment: For practical applications doing a single `log` call no. But for research, this is important. What if the imprecisions cumulate, and the results deviate even more? Imagine a deep neural network with a log-based activation function, which learns something else, when implemented in Python or Matlab.

Comment: It's difficult to say how Matlab gets its value without seeing the implementation. Using the [bilinear expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3535630/1004099) in Python produces the same result as numpy, so they might be using that (I don't know where in the numpy source code it is implemented). I computed the natural log in c and that gave another value, -1.029619417181158 **21776**. The result is inconsistent between languages, which is unsurprising.

Comment: “What if the imprecisions cumulate, and the results deviate even more?” This is why you need numerically stable algorithms, so that rounding errors don’t accumulate. Scientific computing is a field of research for a reason. “ Imagine a deep neural network…” DL will never depend on the 16th digit. DL is usually implemented with 16-bit or even 8-bit floats, speed and energy efficiency are more important than precision.

Comment: My colleagues present a paper on the impact of numerical deviations on ML at NEURIPS. It is not completely out of topic.
https://informationsecurity.uibk.ac.at/pdfs/SHB2023_NEURIPS.pdf

Comment: That is not a very interesting paper, sorry. From the introduction: *“the existence of deviations is not apparent in typical performance metrics, such as test set accuracy.”* Of course not. So what is the problem? Who cares about differences in rounding errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both MATLAB and numpy by default use [64bit float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) that have a 52 bit mantissa. This means the smallest relative step between two float64 numbers is `2**-52 = 2.2e-16`. This means any decimal after the 16th has no significance. The difference you're seeing is probably due to a sligtly different implementation. You can check this by using

```
np.nextafter(a, 1)-a
```

For `a = np.log(0.35714285714285715079)` you get `2.2e-16` which is roughly the size of the [machine precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) `np.finfo(np.float64).eps`.

Even if you look at the input: You're providing more decimals than necessary to completely define a 64-bit float. We can set the number of displaye decimals to 100 and it will still just print 17 digits for this reason:

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=100)
>>> np.array([0.35714285714285715079])
array([0.35714285714285715])
```

The difference between MATLAB and numpy might even be caused by reordering a sum, as floating point addition is not associative. If you do depend on the 16th decimal place then you should use something other than 64bit float. I'd recommend familiarizing yourself with how floating point types are implemented, as it is vital when working with scientific software. And if you'd like, I'd recommend taking a look at the source code of numpy, to see how it is implemented, and compare it to other open libraries.

Comment: Related to this answer, it is worth noting that Matlab's `sum` was recently [changed](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2021/09/07/a-faster-and-more-accurate-sum/) to better deal with round-off errors

Comment: And likewise `np.sum` is inferior to `math.fsum` if you want the last bit of precision